# Is there a website for web developers wanting to give development time to charity?

Tags: social-networking

I'd be willing to invest some time working for a charity, but I feel like I'd be more useful if I get to work in my field (web development). I know that a lot of non-profit are in desperate need for new websites since I already worked for some doing web work.

The thing is the organizations I've worked for were always within my personal network, and lately I ended up with nothing to do in that field. There's only so many non-profits you know personally ^^

**So, is there a website to help non-profit meet with web workers (graphists, devs & co) willing to do some volunteer work for a given amount of time? If not, do you think it would be a good idea to create one?**

Comment: This would be a better fit for http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @chisf: not sure, since this is programming related, generally speaking ^^

Comment: wow, 10 months later and still no answer. i asked myself this question last year as well. marcgg, wanna build one with me?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to 1st question: No, not that I know of.

Answer to 2nd question: Yes, good idea. :)

Alternative: perhaps you can try to google for non-profit and approach them and offer them your interest. Or you could go to some freelance website / forum, post up your info and interest there and wait for them to contact you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with the answer is that you'd waste a lot of time trying to find someone interested in your services. Also some small non-profit don't really have a website or a place with contact info ^^

Comment: Yes, some non-profit might not have a website, but by googling, you might stumble upon some of their contacts in some directory service website (like yellow pages). It is time-consuming, but it is the only way to go right now.

Comment: my other problem with just looking for someone to help is that it's time consuming AND even if I find someone interested, I would still have to find a graphist to help me in this task since I'm only a developer. A sys admin for deployment couldnt hurt either ^^

Comment: @marcgg, yes I understand that problem, that's why I gave "good idea" to your second question :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really have some time and are truly interested in offering your services then you should start looking at what is available in your home town.  There are numerous small non-profit organizations in every town that would love to have someone helping out.  chances are the help they need barely qualifies as technical support (helping manage lists in Excel, running an online survey using a third- party tool, etc...) but you can be sure that your help would be appreciated.  Non-technical people are intimidated by the Internets and any assistance can only help.

Putting together a resource to help non-profits hook up with designers is a great idea but it is also quite ambitious.  If you could pull it off, I'm sure it would be something the community would love to participate in.  However, in the meantime, just call up local groups and ask if they need help.  It is almost guaranteed that they do.

Comment: I already tried contacting some people and did stuff like that. But like I was saying to @gan, this is time consuming. But the main problem with this is me on my own I can't create a full website since my designing skills are quite inexistants ^^ So that's why sometime to get designers & devs together for projects like that would be nice